# Removing specific carousel panes in the jQuery Scrollable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [this Scrollable plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html), and am looking at how to remove a carousel pane from the carousel group.

As an example, if I have 5 carousel windows - how can I programmatically remove the carousel window 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/edit.html)

To remove a particular tab use this function (slightly modified method from the example above):

```
function removeItem(i) { 
    // get handle to scrollable api 
    var api = $("div.scrollable").scrollable(); 

    // remove last item by using jQuery's remove() method 
    api.getItems().eq(i).remove(); 
}

removeItem(0); // will remove first item
removeItem(1); // will remove second
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Ra Yell - have spent alot of time on this page but to no avail. This only demonstrates removing a pane only from the end. What if I want to remove pane number 2 from this example? Would appreciate if you could provide the code to do this as I haven't had much luck. Thanks.

Comment: `api.getItems().eq(1).remove();` - this should remove second pane

Comment: Thanks - will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I had a go at this and from the looks of it, it actually took the carousel pane off at the end even though I indicated pane 2. Just wondering if you have had a chance in testing your code above?

Comment: Yeah, I used firebug on this demo site: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/edit.html then just typed `$('div.scrollable').scrollable().getItems().eq(1).remove();` and second pane was removed.

Comment: Cool - can I ask you how you/where, you did this within Firebug, to test this?

Comment: I just opened that site then typed the code in firebug's console.